# OpenCart URL redirect with query string not working

Tags: php, redirect, opencart

Hoping someone might be able to give me hand with this one.

I'm working on a customer account area on an OpenCart site and there's a section where people can delete pets they have added to their inventory. The delete functionality works and the so does the redirect, but I would like it so that a message shows in a box to confirm that the pet was successfully removed, like it does when one is added. To achieve this I've added a query parameter of "remove=1" into the URL redirect as per the OpenCart documentation but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code in the controller:

```
    $this->load->model('account/pet');

    $pet_info = $this->model_account_pet->removePet($this->request->get['pet_id']);
    if (!isset($pet_info['pet_id'])) {
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/pets', '', 'SSL'));
    }

    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/pets', 'remove=1', 'SSL'));
```

But when it redirects, the query string doesn't appear and therefore the message does not show.

Any help appreciated,

Michael

Comment: is there any piece of code that handles the parameter `remove` at the function `index()` of the `ControllerAccountPet` class?

Comment: and BTW, your code should look like `if(bla bla) {redirect to x} else {redirect to y}` because I'm not sure if `$this->redirect` stops the script after sending the redirection header

Comment: Yes, in the Pets controller, there is this code: `if(isset($this->request->get['remove'])) {
   $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_removed');
  }` - although the if/else statement you suggested works...but the message doesn't show, but I can work on that thank you

Comment: Actually, the message still didn't show - so in the end I handled the $_GET in the template file and that works!

Comment: seems like we must do everything with our hands at the end :D